# file read write with custom buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, io, buffer, read-write

I'm currently fiddling out with raspberry pi gpio, the access files for which are located in `/sys/class/gpio/` directory. Once correct pins are exported, we've to read and write onto the respective gpio files.

Now since those files will only contain either 0 or 1 at a moment, would providing a custom buffer via `pubsetbuf` call a good choice here? The call looks like -

`file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof buf);`

I've read buffers are good for big read/writes since it provides less system calls and less number of read/writes if buffer size matches the required read/writes. But since here there is 0 possibility of big read/writes, only `0`/`1` would be written onto respective files, wouldn't having a large(default) buffer a bad choice here?

Should I set buffer and size as `nullptr` and `0` for direct read/write or some respective size of `0`/`1` chars so that buffering occurs but only for single characters, which is confusing since dosen't it means the same as the first choice? Or should I just leave the buffer size as it is and not even touch this function?

Also if I try to represent `0` and `1` as integers, what type size should my buffer be of? Currently I was doing it with string data type without `pubsetbuf` call, so never thought of that.

*PS - I'm just trying to learn inner workings of c++ and linux so I'm not experimenting on some actual application where I might worsen things :p.*

Comment: Custom buffers should be provided using the `rdbuf(mybuf)` function, `pubsetbuf()` has no effect at the base class version ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf) please).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah okay, I was thrown off by the example on the page. Still my question stands correct if we only replace the function call, since it's more about usage of buffer :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know what went wrong, I peeked this page - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf , and it contains the example of `pubsetbuf` which again as you say has no effect.